# Check changed boolean value MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, report, inner-join

I am trying to get the current status of reports.

I have several tables that are storing basic information:

```
[SDate - DateTime]                 [Value]    [ReportServer] [reportid]
2010-11-16 10:10:00                    1        Server1        1
2010-11-16 10:11:00                    0        Server2        1
2010-11-16 10:12:00                    1        Server1        1
2010-11-16 10:13:00                    1        Server2        1
```

the second table stores the notification data so that each time a report fails to generate and this query runs it will tell me the last status

```
[alertdate - DateTime]                 [Value]   [reportid]
2010-11-16 10:10:00                    1           1
2010-11-16 10:11:00                    0           1
2010-11-16 10:12:00                    1           1
2010-11-16 10:13:00                    1           1
```

if i run my query and the last time the report ran it failed i would need the query to return the reportid that is in a failed state.

The second query does the opposite of sorts i need to know the report that last failed but has successfully run after the failure.

Here is the current query i have that partially works

```
SELECT *
FROM reports
WHERE reportid IN (
  SELECT epr.reportid
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
          lag(t.isup)
    OVER (ORDER BY (reportdate)) AS prev_value
    FROM reportresults t
    WHERE iserrored = 1) t
INNER JOIN reportresults epr
      ON epr.reportid = t.reportid
WHERE t.server != epr.server
      AND prev_value != 0
      AND t.reportid NOT IN (SELECT reportid
                             FROM reportresults
                             WHERE cast(t.reportdate AS datetime)
                                 < cast(reportdate AS datetime)
                                 AND reportid = t.reportid
                                 AND iserrored = 0)
                             GROUP BY epr.endpointid
)
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the errored reports and the errored reports that recovered?

Is my query at all close to what I need?

EDIT

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [Reports](
        [ReportID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ReportTypeID] [int] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [checker].[EndpointResults](
        [ReportResultID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [ReportID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [ReportServerID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [CheckDate] [datetimeoffset](3) NOT NULL,
        [ReportTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Iserrored] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [Message] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReportAlerts](
        [AlertID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [AlertDate] [datetimeoffset](3) NOT NULL,
        [issent] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Alert_issent]  DEFAULT ((0)),
        [ReportServerID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [ReportID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [iserrored] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Alert_iserrored]  DEFAULT ((0))
)
```

FURTHER EXPLANATION:

```
TABLE [Reports]
      [ReportID]        [uniqueidentifier]    NOT NULL,
      [CustomerID]      [int]                 NOT NULL,
      [ReportTypeID]    [int]                 NOT NULL



[reportid]              [customerid]        [reporttypeid]
 ------------------------------------   ----------------      ----------------
8D14EB9C-9C1E-4BBC-A3DE-15202072B1A2    1           0
FF302416-899B-432A-AA8B-E3207CF3C24F    1           0
F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620    1           0



TABLE [checker].[EndpointResults]
      [ReportResultID]  [uniqueidentifier]    NOT NULL,
      [ReportID]        [uniqueidentifier]    NOT NULL,
      [ReportServerID]  [nvarchar](50)        NOT NULL,
      [CheckDate]       [datetimeoffset](3)   NOT NULL,
      [ReportTypeID]    [int]                 NOT NULL,
      [Iserrored]       [bit]                 NOT NULL,
      [Message]         [nvarchar](50)        NOT NULL

ReportResultID                        ReportID                             ReportServerID                     CheckDate                          IsErrored
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----------------------------------- ---------------------------------- ----------
5D78DA02-6D45-42D5-846E-BD17ADA21E9B F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620 Server1                  2016-02-04 20:18:39.459 -06:00     1
ABE92139-3D9D-4C84-96E3-28BBC40AF720 FF302416-899B-432A-AA8B-E3207CF3C24F Server2                  2016-02-04 20:18:34.990 -06:00     0
DC56CFE5-53E5-4CE6-95F4-3816FBC4915A FF302416-899B-432A-AA8B-E3207CF3C24F Server1                      2016-02-04 20:18:34.957 -06:00     0
EA9D6F69-09F9-4BEA-9858-BD10B058CC72 8D14EB9C-9C1E-4BBC-A3DE-15202072B1A2 Server1                              2016-02-04 20:18:34.945 -06:00     0
D45C6316-17B2-462B-8BF9-4B012DBF9D4C 8D14EB9C-9C1E-4BBC-A3DE-15202072B1A2 Server2                              2016-02-04 20:18:34.624 -06:00     0
231CC017-53AC-4F15-B620-B4FB8B0EE6C3 F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620 Server2                              2016-02-04 20:18:34.607 -06:00     1
7582273C-8AA5-4D42-9987-0116868269B8 F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620 Server1                  2016-02-04 20:18:29.461 -06:00     1
C006F277-63A3-4A31-965C-012624322C44 FF302416-899B-432A-AA8B-E3207CF3C24F Server1                  2016-02-04 20:18:24.945 -06:00     0
DF1FE3C1-59DE-47FE-AE3E-DE11B83AFA74 8D14EB9C-9C1E-4BBC-A3DE-15202072B1A2 Server1                  2016-02-04 20:18:24.932 -06:00     0
F05F4102-DFB3-4E98-B4E3-DB94FDD3959A F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620 Server2                  2016-02-04 20:18:24.647 -06:00     0
```

From the above you can see that i have two servers running the same reports
if i was to query the above 10 records it would show me that report `F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620` is in an errored state and no server 
has sucessfully run it since `2016-02-04 20:18:24.647 -06:00` so the query would only return `F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620` as it is the only report currently errored out.

the next query woudld join the alerts table and tell me has the admin been notified that the report is in an errored state so join the top table with the alerts table where ReportID from above equals reportid from alerts and if there is no record of an alert after the last failed creport result this query tells me that i need to insert a new alert and send it

then the last would assume that the newest entry in the above 10 tables shows IsErrored = 0
so at `2016-02-04 20:18:24.647 -06:00` the report started to fail
it failed again at `2016-02-04 20:18:29.461 -06:00` and `2016-02-04 20:18:34.607 -06:00` the next sucessful run was at `2016-02-04 20:18:39.459 -06:00`

so the query needs to return only reportid `F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620` that does not contain a record in the alerts table.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

edit: r.e. potentially many servers, understood.

Ok then... about this for identifying reportID's that have are in error (e.g. have 2+ isErrored values of 1)

### Find Most Recent Runs...

Get most recent run attempt for each reportID + serverID pairs...

```
select a.reportID        as reportID
     , a.reportServerID  as serverID
     , a.checkDate       as mostRecentTime
     , a.isErrored       as errFlag
from checker.EndpointResults a
where not exists (
   select 1 from checker.EndpointResults b
   where b.reportID = a.reportID
     and b.reportServerID = a.reportServerID
     -- This next and-condition makes sure that whatever
     -- record wechoose for a given ReprtID + ServerID
     -- above is the most recent record.
     and b.checkDate > a.checkDate )
```

So if this worked (let me know) then we're in a position to count how many fails each
report currently has.

### Count Fails by Report

```
with MostRecentRuns( reportID, serverID, mostRecentTime, errFlag ) as (
  -- Start by filtering out only the last runs for our reports on all servers.
  -- Note this will not detect reports that NEVER run, or just ran ok "one time"
  -- (which could be a problem if it last ran like over a year ago.)
  select a.reportID        as reportID
       , a.reportServerID  as serverID
       , a.checkDate       as mostRecentTime
       , a.isErrored       as errFlag
  from checker.EndpointResults a
       where not exists (
          select 1 from checker.EndpointResults b
          where b.reportID = a.reportID
            and b.reportServerID = a.reportServerID
            and b.checkDate > a.checkDate )
)
, FailCountsByReport ( reportID, errFlagSum ) as (
   select a.reportID
        , sum(a.errSum) as errFlagSum
   from MostRecentRuns
   group by a.reportID
)
select *
from FailCountsByReport
where errFlagSum >= 2
```

---

### Older...  ignore for now.

This part is possibly of historical interest in clairyfing the defintion of "error"

For now the notes & analysis below may be useful, but the SQL fragments are not

(so please don't try to run them).

So... I think we're getting closer. :-)
Thank you for the additional detail, the sample data helps.

Let's trim the ID#'s down a little, turns out the last 4 digits are distinct in this data sample so that will make it easier talk about "B620" (vs. writing "F31F2C20-7182-45C6-93EE-FB332740B620" all the time).

If we ORDER BY **ReportID** and **CheckDate** it looks like this...

### Sample data for EndpointResults table

```
+---------+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
| Report  |  Report |  Reprot   |  Check       | Is      |
| ResultID|  ID     |  ServerID |  Date <1>    | Errored |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
|  959A   |  B620   |  Server2  | 20:18:24.647 |    0    |
|  69B8   |  B620   |  Server1  | 20:18:29.461 |    1    |
|  E6C3   |  B620   |  Server2  | 20:18:34.607 |    1    |
|  1E9B   |  B620   |  Server1  | 20:18:39.459 |    1    |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
|  F720   |  C24F   |  Server2  | 20:18:34.990 |    0    |
|  915A   |  C24F   |  Server1  | 20:18:34.957 |    0    |
|  2C44   |  C24F   |  Server1  | 20:18:24.945 |    0    |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
|  CC72   |  B1A2   |  Server1  | 20:18:34.945 |    0    |
|  9D4C   |  B1A2   |  Server2  | 20:18:34.624 |    0    |
|  FA74   |  B1A2   |  Server1  | 20:18:24.932 |    0    |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------------+---------+
   <1> For CheckDate only HH.MM.SS.MMM shown,
       prefix with "2016-02-04 " for complete DATETIME
```

### Simplified Scenarios

I think your definition of "error" is still incomplete.

Let me illustrate with an example: which of these reports are "errored out" ?

In these Simplified Scenarios I'm cutting the time down to just minutes & seconds.

```
+------+------+-------+---+
|RepID | SrvID|  Time |Err|
+------+------+-------+---+
| A001 |   1  | 20:00 | 0 |   Report ID A001 is obviously fine,
|    " |   2  | 20:05 | 0 |   no errors at all.
|    " |   1  | 20:10 | 0 |
|    " |   2  | 20:15 | 0 |
+------+------+-------+---+
| B002 |   1  | 20:00 | 0 |   B002 is obviously a problem,
|    " |   2  | 20:05 | 0 |   all recent runs on each server
|    " |   1  | 20:10 | 1 |   failed.
|    " |   2  | 20:15 | 1 |
+------+------+-------+---+
| C003 |   1  | 20:00 | 0 |   C003 is less clear.
|    " |   2  | 20:05 | 0 |   Latest run on Server #1 was ok.
|    " |   1  | 20:10 | 0 |   Latest run on Server #2 failed.
|    " |   2  | 20:15 | 1 |   So is C003 a problem? It was sort of ok.
+------+------+-------+---+
| D004 |   1  | 20:00 | 1 |   D004 is less clear.
|    " |   2  | 20:05 | 1 |   Latest run on Server #1 failed,
|    " |   1  | 20:10 | 1 |   but latest run on Server #2 was ok.
|    " |   2  | 20:15 | 0 |   So should D004 be a problem?
+------+------+-------+---+
```

**Error = ALL FAILED?**
Do you want "error" to mean ALL server's latest attempts to run the report failed?

If so, only B002 would be an "error" in the above example.

**Error = ANY FAILED?**
Or should "error" mean ANY server's latest attempt had 1 failure?

If so, then B002, C003, and D004 would indicate "errors".

**Error = ONLY LATEST ATTEMPT FAILED?**

In this variant, only B002 and C003 would indicate "errors".

Let me know what definition of "error" works best for your situation.

---

### Older version, pre data sample

*For now, please ignore from here to end, pending resolution above questions r.e. precise definition of "error".*

Edits: Please re-retry first & second SQL Examples (example#3 not ready yet, will adjust if fist & second work reasonably well).

Edits: Thank you for adding the table definitions and column names.

Ok.... here are table definitions with some space padding (makes it easier for me to read column names):

```
TABLE [Reports]
      [ReportID]        [uniqueidentifier]    NOT NULL,
      [CustomerID]      [int]                 NOT NULL,
      [ReportTypeID]    [int]                 NOT NULL

TABLE [checker].[EndpointResults]
      [ReportResultID]  [uniqueidentifier]    NOT NULL,
      [ReportID]        [uniqueidentifier]    NOT NULL,
      [ReportServerID]  [nvarchar](50)        NOT NULL,
      [CheckDate]       [datetimeoffset](3)   NOT NULL,
      [ReportTypeID]    [int]                 NOT NULL,
      [Iserrored]       [bit]                 NOT NULL,
      [Message]         [nvarchar](50)        NOT NULL

TABLE [dbo].[ReportAlerts]
      [AlertID]         [int] IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
      [AlertDate]       [datetimeoffset](3)   NOT NULL,
      [issent]          [bit]                 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Alert_issent]  DEFAULT ((0)),
      [ReportServerID]  [nvarchar](50)        NULL,
      [ReportID]        [uniqueidentifier]    NULL,
      [iserrored]       [bit]                 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Alert_iserrored]  DEFAULT ((0))
```

Do the SQL examples shown below actually run?

If yes, are they going in a useful direction for you?

Your SQL seems harder than it needs to be.

Let's summarize the basic questions you could ask:

### Summary of Questions We Can Ask About Your Reports

Is the following list of questions complete (or maybe complete enough for you to get started)?

```
Which reports have never run?
Which reports ran ok with zero errors?
Which reports ran ok but have 1+ errors? (which I think
    is what you were describing as your "second query
    does the opposite of sorts...")
Which reports never ran ok (e.g. only 1+ errors)?
added: Which reports have errors but no Alerts (yet).
```

So. Let's start by counting how your reports are doing:
(Caution - SQL not tested, almost certainly contains typos)

### First SQL example

edit, fixed reportID counter to use case statement.

edited, using revised table & column names.

Question: is it important to worry about Alerts at this point?
Or is it sufficient to flag which reports have *any* errors (ignoring how many alerts there are)?

I don't have enough context to tell whether you want to count EndpointResults or Alerts (or maybe both).

If you need to count Report+Alerts then you'll want to join against ReportAlerts instead of EndpointResults as shown.

```
select a.reportID
     , sum( case when b.reportID is null then 0 else 1 end ) as runCnt
     , sum( coalesce( b.Iserrored, 0 ) ) as errCnt
from  Reports a
left join checker.EndpointResults b
       on b.ReportID = a.ReportID
group by a.reportID
order by a.reportID
```

Note that putting a coalesce in the sum()s handles any null values that could show up if the left join finds no corresponding reportid in ReportResults (which seems likely if any reports have never attempted to run).

For **runCnt** (total run attempts) we're just counting how many non-null reportID's we see in ReportResults for a given reportid.

For **errCnt** (total # errors) we're just counting how many non-zero IsErrored values we see in ReportResults for a given reportid.  Since the value here is either 0 or 1, sum is sufficient.  (This would be more complex if you had multiple error codes beyond '1=errror'.)

### Second SQL example (fold Alert status)

```
with ERRCOUNTS ( reportid, runCnt, errCnt ) as (
   select a.reportID
        , sum( case when b.reportID is null then 0 else 1 end ) as runCnt
        , sum( coalesce( b.Iserrored, 0 ) ) as errCnt
   from  Reports a
   left join checker.EndpointResults b
          on b.ReportID = a.ReportID
   group by a.reportID
), ALERTCOUNTS ( reportid, runCnt, errCnt, alertCnt, alertErrCnt ) as (
   select a.reportID
        , a.runCnt
        , a.errCnt
        , sum( case when b.reportID is null then 0 else 1 end ) as alertCnt
        , sum( coalesce( b.iserrored, 0 ) ) as alertErrCnt
   from  ERRCOUNTS a
   left join dbo.ReportAlerts b
          on b.ReportID = a.ReportID
)
select * from ALERTCOUNTS
order by reportid
```

If this makes sense (and my assumptions hold), then we can use it to answer the above questions.  Consider the following example w/the CASE that filter different kinds of reports "status categories" from our basic runCnt & errCnt query....

### Third SQL example (not ready yet, do not run)

edited: using revised table names.

```
with REPCOUNTS ( reportid, runCnt, errCnt ) as (
   select a.reportID
        , sum( coalesce( b.reportID,  0 ) as runCnt
        , sum( coalesce( b.Iserrored, 0 ) as errCnt
   from  Reports a
   left join checker.EndpointResults b
          on b.ReportID = a.ReportID
   group by a.reportID
   -- lets add a date range because you'll want to focus on
   -- arbitrary time windows eventually instead everything
   -- over the last 10 years or however long you keep history.
   where datepart( YEAR, b.CheckDate ) = 2010
      and datepart( MONTH, b.CheckDate ) = 11

)
select
   case when a.runCnt = 0        then 'NEVER'
        when a.errCnt = 0        then 'OK, 0 ERRS'
        when a.errCnt < a.runCnt then 'OK, 1+ ERRS'
        when a.errCnt = a.runCnt then 'TOTAL FAIL'
        else '** Should never happen **'
   end as RUN_STATUS
 , a.reportID
 , r.runCnt
 , r.errCnt
from REPCOUNTS
```

I went back and forth between doing the "case logic" as a series of unions but the case logic seems cleaner.

Does this get you closer to where you wanted to be?

Comment: Added the table structure above

Comment: @cobra2599, thanks for the table & column names, let me know if the SQL examples are going in the right direction (and whether they actually run) or you're after a different kind of summary.

Comment: i need two queries
1) returns any reports in a errored state
2) any reports in a non errored state that an alert has not been sent to me

Comment: r.e. unique id: oops, will tweak.  r.e. non-errored state, that makes sense.  will start by adding alert counts.

Comment: @cobra2599, ok please try sql examples #1 and #2.

Comment: I added more details above

Comment: @cobra2599 - the additional data examples help, please review my question in the answer about the specific nature of "error".

Comment: Error = two or more failed

Comment: Keep in mind that there are a lot more than two servers that will report back with status in the data i am testing with two so the error means two or more not limited to two

Comment: @cobra2599: I added an sql example to find reports with 2+ errors on their most recent runs.  Is that going in the right direction?